# Creating own iterator for double vectors

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am a bit new at c++, so the question may be without any meaning, so, sorry about that in advance.
So, i have a class of hashtable, my hashtable is vector of vectors, it means that i used

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > htable;
```

My task is - create own iterator with operation ++, --, -> and *. I wrote this

```
    class hashTable
{
public: 
    hashTable(int size);
    ~hashTable();
    void add(std::string s);
    bool inHash(std::string s);
    void deletestr(std::string s);
    void printall();
    int maxcoll();

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > htable;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > newhtable;
    int hfunc(std::string s);
    void reallocate();
    int M;
    int teksize;
    int issame(std::string a, std::string b);

    class myiterator{
        myiterator();
        myiterator operator*();
        myiterator operator++();
        myiterator operator--();
        myiterator operator->();

    };
    myiterator begin() {return htable.begin()}
    myiterator end() {return htable.end()}

};
```

I think, that i understand what the interator is, but now i suppose that i was wrong, so when i try to compile this, there is a mistake in lines

```
myiterator begin() {return htable.begin()}
myiterator end() {return htable.end()}
```

/Users/ratkke/Programms/c++/mipt/tasks/#5/myhash.cpp:37:29: error: no viable conversion from 'iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter') to 'hashTable::myiterator'
        myiterator begin() {return htable.begin()}
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/ratkke/Programms/c++/mipt/tasks/#5/myhash.cpp:29:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter') to 'const hashTable::myiterator &' for 1st argument
        class myiterator{

And i don't know why. Also, can you tell me about realisation of iterator(or just link to article) for iterator for vectors, because i can't understand how i must implement all this operators.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first question you need to ask is what type of iterator it needs to be. There are basically 6 standard iterator classes. Trivial/Input/Output/Forward/Bidirectional/Random  See: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html I would suggest starting with a Forward iterator. http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ForwardIterator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement your `myiterator`. There are lots of way to do that, but at very least you must add something to `myiterator`. For instance

```
class myiterator{
public:
    myiterator();
    myiterator(std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >& v, int ii, int jj) : 
        vec(v), i(ii), j(jj) {}
    std::string operator*();
    myiterator& operator++(); // prefix operator
    myiterator operator++(int); // postfix operator
    myiterator& operator--(); // prefix operator
    myiterator operator--(int); // postfix operator
    std::string* operator->();
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >& vec; // the vector we are iterating over
    int i; // the position in the vector (first dimension)
    int j; // the position in the vector (second dimension)
};

myiterator begin() {return myiterator(htable, 0, 0);}
```

Lots of other ways to do it, and the above may not be exactly what you want, but hopefully this gives you the idea, `myiterator` must have some data members that hold the vector being iterated over and the position reached so far.

Also note the return type of `operator*` is wrong, it should (presumably) be `std::string`. Some of the other operators don't look right either, I've put what I think is correct in the code.

Comment: I didn't understand this
    'myiterator(std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >& v, int ii, int jj) : 
        vec(v), i(ii), j(jj) {}'
  lines, what did you do that? And why in some iterators do we have pointers? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ratkke, it's just a constructor to construct a myiterator object. Iterators have pointers if that's what you need to implement them. Each iterator is going to be implemented differently, you could probably use pointers for this iterator if you wished.

Comment: -1: Not sufficient. You miss many of the characteristics required by an iterator (assignable/comparable). If you want iterators to work correctly with algorithms you need to set them up so iterator_traits<> work correctly. Hashes don't usually require bi-directional iterators so the decrement operators are unusual (but nothing wrong with supporting more than you need too).

Comment: @LokiAstari It wasn't meant to be sufficient, just meant to be a start. Trying to explain every nuance of writing an iterator to a beginner would not be helpful IMO. The OP will find out about the issues you raise as he goes along. And if you read some of his follow up questions you'll see that has already happened.